# France Residence Permit Cancellation During German Employment Visa Processing Period

Tags: france, indian-citizens

A friend who holds an Indian passport was pursuing a doctoral course in France, and had a French *Titre de Sejour* which is valid for another two years. He has discontinued his studies in the French institute following the completion of a Master's degree, and was accepted for a doctoral program in a German institute. He will soon be applying for a Type D German National Visa in the Consulate of Germany in Paris.

I understand that his passport and BRP will be returned to him while the consulate processes his application (approximately 2 months), and he will be invited to have the visa stamped.

Since he has discontinued his studies in the French institute, can the French institute report completion of studies to OFII, leading to the curtailment the French residence permit before he receives his German visa? Does he have any rights similar to UK residents with visa applications in progress? If his residence permit is cancelled, does he have any recourse to complete the German visa application, considering that he was *required* to apply within France, which is as of now his country of residence, and the consulate does not provide any expedited services?

I understand that he is allowed to travel, since his passport and BRP have been returned to him. Will travelling outside the Schengen area cause any problems?

Comment: Who are **they**? If Germany: no, since one country does not the authority to invalidate a residence permit of another country. Having 2 resident permits is plausible : work in one and live in another.

Comment: I was referring to France. I'm aware that UK universities are required to report to the Home Office if a student completes a course earlier than expected, and the Home Office then curtails the BRP.